# Extract Sharepoint 2013 wiki page HTML Source / Display wiki page without master layout in iFrame?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

What I am trying to achieve is to find a way of displaying a wiki page content in a floating iFrame ( and of course keep the styling )  for a tool that I am developing for our employees. Right now the tool I made is using jQuery dialog box to display a specific document / pdf, For compatibility and usability purposes I would really like to upgrade that so it uses a wiki page instead of documents / PDFs.The problem that I am facing is that there is no really direct link to the content of a Sharepoint wiki page instead the only available direct link is the one to the page all together with all the navigation menus, option panel, user panel etc. I want to avoid using javascrip to strip away these elements. Instead I am simply trying to find out if sharepoint 2013 has some more elegant way of providing the content such as: Web service or javascript SP API.

My ideas so far:

REST Url to give the content back? I know for sure it works for lists and libraries but I couldn't find anything in the REST API About wiki page content
SP.js ? Couldn't find anything about that either
Anyways, it could be possible that I have overlooked things, or probably haven't searched hard enough. However, any help is very very welcome. If you don't know about a concrete solution I would be very happy with nice suggestions too :)

If there is nothing out of the box I will have to get to my backup plan of a jQuery solution to get the page and strip off all unnecessary content and keep the styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are on the right track with REST API, in Enterprise Wiki Page the content is stored in `PublishingPageContent` property.

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve Enterprise Wiki Page content:

```
var getWikiPageContent =  function (webUrl,itemId,result) {
    var listTitle = "Pages";
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/items(" + itemId + ")/PublishingPageContent";
    $.getJSON(url,function( data ) {
        result(data.value); 
    });
}
```

**Usage**

```
getWikiPageContent('https://contoso.sharepoint.com/',1,function(pageContent){
   console.log(pageContent); 
});
```

Comment: Firs of all thanks a lot for the answer it works awesome for Enterprise Wiki. It must have had something to do with sharepoint List, I just didn't think it would be as simple as that... I have used REST API for lists before, never thought it's the same concept for the pages. This example however didn't work for Publishing Site, even though i verified the name of the list and all that. Btw in my case I found a little bit more useful way of using the REST API:
mysite.sharepoint.com/wikiSite/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items?$filter=Title eq 'home'

The filter option is awesome ;)

Answer (score 0):

And something for those of you who like to have more than one different examples:

```
 var inner_content;
var page_title = "home";

$.ajax({
        url: "https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/MyEnterpriseWikiSite/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items?$filter=Title eq '" + page_title +"'",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {

            if (data.d.results[0]) {
                inner_content = data.d.results[0].PublishingPageContent;
            }

        },
       error: function(){ //Show Error here }
   });
```

That's what did the job for me.

This example fetches the inner content of an Enterprise wiki page by Title( make sure you are not using the Name of the page, although Title and Name can be given the same string value, they are different fields in sharepoint 2013 )